# Django User's DetailVew affects authenticated User

Tags: django, detailview

I tried to display information about User (profile page) using DetailView. It works but when I open a DetailView of User for some reason Django thinks that I am authenticated as this user. For an example if I log out, open some User's DetailView, Django starts to think that I am logged in as this User. I can see problems as base.html shows currently logged user and changes if user is not authenticated. Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks!

views.py

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<int:pk>/<str:username>', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <article class = 'media content-section'>
    <div class="media">
        <img class="avatar-image rounded-circle" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        </div>
    <div class = 'media-body'>
        <div class='article-metadata'>
            <h3>Профиль {{user.username}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="article-content">
            <p>{{user.first_name}}</p>
            <p>{{user.email}}</p>
            <p>{{user.profile.birthdate}}</p>
            <p>{{user.date_joined}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="far fa-user-circle" title="Пользователь"> {{user.username}}</i></a>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the user is not logged in, but an issue with your code. When you are sending the `User` data to template with context parameter `user`, it gets mixed up with `request.user`. And interestingly, if you try with that user (which is sent from DetailView), it will show is_authenticated true, so you would see the logged in user in based html. For example:

```
user = User.objects.first()
user.is_authenticated()  # It will return True
```

To prevent this, you need to send a different context parameter for DetailView. Like:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "profile_user"
    ...
```

and in template, use `profile_user`. Also, if you want only the logged in user to access that particular View, then you should subclass it from [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin). For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
   ...
```

Comment: Using `profile_user` as a new `context_object_name` and using it in the DetaiView didn't work for me. I still see the `profile_user.is_authenticated` as `True` for all the users...

Comment: You have to use `user.is_authenticated` in template.

Comment: I did it and I still see `True` for all users... I uploaded the relevant parts of my code here https://codeshare.io/axDBWR in case you would like to have a quick look on it. Maybe I'm missing something. Thank you for your valuable time :)

Comment: can you try to log out and then go to that url again please?

Comment: Still the same, even in an incognito window :( I recorded this sceencast for you: https://streamable.com/a2q5mn

Comment: It is behaving the same as expected. `user` here is the logged in user. If I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to solve it by a if clause in template `user.pk == profie_user.pk`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the point here, but if you mean using `user.pk == profile_user.pk` as I did here https://codeshare.io/axDBWR (I updated the `profile.html` part), only the current user will be able to check whether his own account is logged in (and that will always be true), and he will see that all the rest of accounts are offline. My original problem is that if only a bunch of users (but not all of them) are online, I will see that all the registered users are online, regardless if they are logged in or not. I will keep trying more solutions, thank you again.

Comment: probably what you want is `profile_user.user.is_active` assuming is_active is a field which is True when user is activated.